# What does the right light/circle icon mean in AnkhSVN?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ankhsvn

When I add a new file to my project, it gets added with the red light icon shown below.  It seems that, while it modifies the project file XML itself, the file I added does not get marked to be added to the repo.  When I check in the project, the change to add the file to the project gets checked into SVN, but the file I added does not.  When others get latest on the project, VS reports a missing file.

To get the new file added to SVN, I have to manually add it through the context menu, but I don't have to do this with any of the other projects/solutions I work on.  It's only this one.

What do I have to do to get files I add to my project automatically flagged to be added to the repo as well?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's such a small picture, it's hard to see, but is it the red circle with a minus / dash (-).

To me, it looks like "ignored" but you have a dark theme, so it's quite possible the "white dash" is actually transparent and showing the theme through... Or ankhsvn has different themes of the icons I've shown below and matches it based upon the theme...

I have no idea why you'd want to ignore the c# files but that's what it looks like

[image]

[Source](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/wiki/Faq/#head-820ac7702a64176d3ebe9fd409)

If you find the icon in Windows Explorer / File Explorer (or Apple/Linux equivalent) it may show the a larger version of the same icon

Comment: It was ignored.  Somehow, I ended up recursively ignoring every folder in my project folder while trying to only ignore bin/obj folders.